# Android adMob : ads not showing (tried everything)

Tags: android, admob

I have an issue with AdMob ads not showing in my test app on a physical devices. I've pretty much browsed all similar questions here, no luck. So I have the classic AdView declaration in my xml :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adUnitId="my_actual_publisher_id"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

My Manifest contains needed permissions, ads activity and Google Play Services :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>


    <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I made sure that there was enough space for my ad : I put it in a TableRow, and next TableRow in line has enough space to show. The space "reserved" for my AdView is consistent with what I would expect.

In the corresponding fragment onCreate(), I request a new ad (I've debugged that piece of code, it is correctly executed) :

```
AdView adView = (AdView) result.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("my_real_device_id").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

My AdMob dashboard doesn't show any request ... what did I do wrong ? Thanks

EDIT : a strange fact maybe worth mentioning : I tried to move the TableRow containing my ad upwards in the TableLayout, just in case it was a matter of rendering space or similar. I now have class cast exception when I try to programmatically get a View that used to be *before* my ad, and which is now *after* :

Button clearButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.clearButton);

In my activity.onCreate() I was doing the code above to perform some initialization, this code now fails with exception :

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableRow cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

It is as if my R class was not recompiled, and its pointers leading to wherever !!!???

Comment: What do you see in the logcat ( related to Admob tags) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to add this simple code in my application. Hope it would help you too... :)

```
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-7742695752659854/6319679360"; // admob id

// ******************************** For Admob

    private void createBanner() {
        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        /*
         * Ad unit name : MobilePASystemBanner in the AdMob Website. App Name :
         * MobilePASystem .
         */
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        /*
         * Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
         * until the ad is loaded.
         */
           // a linear layout at the bottom to display an add (make it in your xml also)
        mlnr_displayBanner.addView(adView);  

        /*
         * Create an ad request. 
         */
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

        /*
         * Start loading the ad in the background.
         */
        try {
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Call this method where you want to display an add.

**Add this to your manifest:**

```
<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
     <activity
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Don't forget to add the library.

************** Check if you are taking your Add unit id from here  *******************

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much what I have ... I must be real close because for instance when I forgot the "adSize" in AdView definition I had a nice warning showing up where my ad should have been. I'm now thinking a) problem in the xmlns b) incorrect publisher id (I'm not using the same as you, mine starts at "pub-" not "ca-app-")

Comment: Well " ca-app-pub- " is the prefix to be used. If this keyword is not their in your id, then i am pretty sure there is some mistake in the admob id.

Comment: I have attached an image in the answer. You can check if your add unit id is like this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tonight. I had my doubts when I realized that with the "pub-" alone adMob cannot distinguish between two apps from the same publisher. Strange things is that I used that ID because that is pretty much the one I figured out from everything I could read on the internet ... guess I read wrong :)

Comment: YES, that was it !Thanks for your help, it now works perfectly fine :)